# How do you create a batch file on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

The icon is for a text file and when I click on the icon it asks me what program to open it with.

```
// cd c:\mysite
// node index.js
// exit
```

Comment: The "quality standards" are not there to make you add random text. What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried? How does it fail? What icon are you talking about? Have you made the file executble? What are the contents of your batch file?

Comment: Same way you create them in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 processes the default `.bat` and `.cmd` extensions, the same as previous versions. It may be possible that your file associations have changed.

Do the `//` in  your code indicate comments? Batch scripts use `REM` or `::` to indicate a comment.

If you are using Windows 8, you should look into PowerShell. It is much more flexible than batch scripts, backwards compatible, not to mention batch scripting is deprecated.

Comment: Citation needed on batch scripting being deprecated.